# rollapply with a function taking a matrix returns "incorrect number of dimensions"

Tags: r, finance, rollapply

I designed my own function called `SharpeRatio(data)`

Where data is an nx2 matrix.

The function works fine for a given matrix dat, however when I try to use `rollapply(dat, 20, SharpeRatio)` I get the following error: **Error in dat[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions**

The following is the function definition:

```
SharpeRatio <- function(dat){
  Returns = dat[,1]
  RiskFree = dat[,2]

  ER = (Returns - RiskFree)/100
  Volatility = sd(Returns/100)
  return((exp(mean(log(1+ER))) - 1)/Volatility)
}
```

Comment: Indeed that is what's missing then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rollapply` works by column unless the `by.column=FALSE` argument is used so try this:

```
rollapply(dat, 20, SharpeRatio, by.column = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 7):

`rollapply` applies a function to *rolling margins of an array*.  But it does this column-by-column.  That is, it does not present an array to your function, but presents vectors N times over (N=2 in your case).

Here's an example:

```
(m <- matrix(1:10, ncol=2))
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    6
## [2,]    2    7
## [3,]    3    8
## [4,]    4    9
## [5,]    5   10
```

We'll `rollapply` a `mean`, and see what gets passed in at each iteration:

```
y <- rollapply(m, width=2, FUN=function(x) {print(x); mean(x)})
## [1] 1 2
## [1] 2 3
## [1] 3 4
## [1] 4 5
## [1] 6 7
## [1] 7 8
## [1] 8 9
## [1]  9 10
```

No matrices are passed to the function, just individual vectors.  `rollapply` then packages the result up as an array in the correct shape:

```
y
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]  1.5  6.5
## [2,]  2.5  7.5
## [3,]  3.5  8.5
## [4,]  4.5  9.5
```

The fix is in Mr. Grothendieck's comment, to pass `by.column=FALSE` to `rollapply`:

```
z <- rollapply(m, width=2, by.column=FALSE, FUN=function(x) {print(x); colMeans(x)})
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    1    6
## [2,]    2    7
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    2    7
## [2,]    3    8
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    3    8
## [2,]    4    9
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    4    9
## [2,]    5   10
```

Here, matrices of two rows each are being passed to the function.  The result is the same as above:

```
z
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]  1.5  6.5
## [2,]  2.5  7.5
## [3,]  3.5  8.5
## [4,]  4.5  9.5
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Matthew. Did not know that it doesnt take arrays (I had the function initially designed for two inputs, but then thought to go around it by passing an array). What would be the right way to do a rolling window application on a function that requires to inputs (and where the windows roll simultaneously)?

Comment: @msmf14 Your idea isn't off-base.  See the edit.  If Mr. Grothendieck enters this as an answer, I'll roll back and you should accept his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since the current roll apply taking a matrix returns "incorrect number of dimension", because it is not meant to take a matrix. I wrote my own one

```
rollmatapply <- function(m,by=100,FUN)
{
  v = vector()  
  for(i in 1:(nrow(m)-by))
  {
    v[i] = do.call(FUN,list(m[i:(by+i-1),]))
  }
  v
}
```

Comment: this is not a good answer, you should add a reason why write his own is a preferred approad